# Flex4, Spark s:VideoPlayer

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

2 questions:

1) Is the new spark s:videoPlayer recommended to play videos ? Or should I build by myself with DisplayVideo components... adding controls.. etc etc ?

2) How can I customize the s:videoPlayer components ? What's the easiest way, for example, to fade in / fade out controls, when the mouse move over the video ?

Should I extend the videoPlayer component and modify it ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I told you another time or not..you can take a look on [OSMF](http://osmf.org/) if you want to build your custom player, it is a project developed in Adobe exactly for that, and is free (open source).